SonarQube PR decoration with GitHub Actions and GitHub, but inline code decoration not working?
I am using our enterprise SonarQube server and doing PR decoration using GitHub Actions. The scan and PR analysis happens fine and in the end I get the GitHub comment on PR analysis, however I do not get any inline code analysis in GitHub. Is this expected or I am missing something? Below is the code in actions that I am running:
 ./gradlew sonar -Paexp.sonar.login=${{ secrets.SONARQUBE_TOKEN }} \
      -Dsonar.host.url=${{ vars.SONAR_URL }} \
      -Dsonar.login=${{ secrets.SONARQUBE_TOKEN }} \
      -Dsonar.projectName=${{ needs.build-system-check.outputs.repo-name }} \
      -Dsonar.projectKey=amex-eng.${{ needs.build-system-check.outputs.repo-name }}.git \
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${{ github.event.number }} \
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${{ github.HEAD_REF }} \
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${{ github.BASE_REF }} \
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.repository=${{ github.repository }} \
      -Dsonar.scm.provider=Github \
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.provider=Github \
      -Dsonar.java.binaries=build/classes \
      -Dsonar.java.libraries=build/libs/*.jar \
      -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true \
      --stacktrace

In SonarQube Server:

In GitHub the bot summarized the PR decoration as a comment, however I cannot see any inline decoration comments in the GitHub PR. What could be missing or is this expected behaviour?


Not sure about the negative vote, its a simple question, i wanted to know if the sonarqube has integration with Github to decorate the PR code inline? I have followed the sonarqube integration guide so far its just giving a consolidated link to the sonarqube dashboard but not actually decorating the PR in Github?
